# Not able to load dynamic variables values in url in nodejs es6 string

Tags: javascript, node.js

My code is as shown below :

`let urlString = https://${process.env.API_KEY}:${process.env.API_TOKEN}${process.env.SUBDOMAIN}/v1/Accounts/${process.env.ID}/Calls/connect`

But somehow `API_KEY , API_TOKEN , SUBDOMAIN and ID` variables values are not getting added in the url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you set the backticks like this?

```js
let urlString = `https://${process.env.API_KEY}:${process.env.API_TOKEN}${process.env.SUBDOMAIN}/v1/Accounts/${process.env.ID}/Calls/connect`;
```

I can't see them in your example.